# Is there an alternative to display: none; or position: absolute; when trying to remove an elements spacing from the flow of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a filter feature that filters through cards using javascript. I do this by removing a "isVisible" class from the card if it does not match the selected category.

My question is, is there a way to remove the spacing a card takes up when its not currently visible on the screen? As the cards that are visible have blank spaces next to them due to the other cards that are hidden.

Here is the current code:
https://codepen.io/Jaromme/pen/poKXLLM

Is there some way I'm able to play the transition in a css keyframe animation or how it is currently, wait a certain amount of time in javascript, and then apply `display: none;`?

Any ideas would be greatful

I've tried to use `display: none;` , but that completely removes the transition I'm using. I've also tried using `position: absolute;` but that's causing an undesirable effect on the animation.

Comment: what is your desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reduce the div heigth/width/padding till it gets 0

For example:

```
@keyframes animation{
0%{height:200px;}
/*...Some medium values*/
100%{height:0px;}}
```